# How can you define the object in an array of items for mongoose schema

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

is the best practice when creating a object inside of an array to simply define an object inside of an array? How would mongodb know to expect an array, and would query on this array be efficent?

for example in this schema

```
const vancouverSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        jobs: {
            retail: {
                type:Array
            },
            general_labour: {
                type:Array
            },
            sales: {
                type:Array
            },
            government: {

            }

         },
    }
)
```

would it be best practice to do simply

```
retail: [{
    title: {
        type: String
    },
    description: {
        type:String
    },
    pay: {
        type:Number
    }
}]
```

VS

```
retail: {
    type:Array
},
```

the attempt being to create a simple schema for a city and its various categories without much cognitive overhead for this part of the design.

This is an example of Vancouver Schema, but I will have 15-20++ city schema, simply copy and paste to create collections dynamically, and because there is so much to keep track of, it seems like the simplest way to do it. I know, its bad to copy paste, but.. is it not permitted for high level design? rather than introduce bugs by trying some clever way, thanks everyone.

```
const vancouverSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        jobs: {
            retail: [
            {
                title: {
                    type: String
                },
                description: {
                    type: String
                },
                pay: {
                    type: Number
                },
                contact_email: {
                    type: String
                }
            },
                {
        timestamps: true
                }

            ],
            general_labour: {
                type:Array
            },
            sales: {
                type:Array
            },
            government: {

            }

         },
        for_sale: {
            free: {
                type:Array
            },
            antiques: {
                type:Array

            },
            appliances: {
                type:Array

            }
        },
        housing:{
        apt: {
                type:Array
        },
        office_commerical:{
                type:Array
        }
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: Could you give us an example of what a `vancouverSchema` object looks like please?

Comment: I think I gave what you asked for, not sure.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear.  Can you show us the object/JSON that you will feed into `vancouverSchema`?

Comment: basically the idea is vancouverSchema will be a collection, then I will feed something to jobs for example, with title, etc. the idea is to create seperate cities, then to push post's into that city, seperating the category of posts via keeping them in arrays.

Comment: So PLEASE show us what a document from the collection looks like.  We can't help you with the recipe if you don't tell us the ingredients.

Comment: Sorry, I dont have any documents yet.. I am still trying to figure out how to create a space for that content, I hope that makes sense, I am trying at a high level to see how I would hold that data, I did not create any data yet

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209490/discussion-between-jcx3x-and-larz).

Answer (score 1):

You can do in this way:

```js
const vancouverSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    jobs: {
        retail: [
            {
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'newSchemaCreated'
            }
        ],
        general_labour: {
            type: [Number]
        },
        sales: {
            type: [Boolean]
        },
        government: {}
    }
})
```

For retail would be better, if you create another schema. And if you have anything else like the retail property, you should do the same. Because put things too much nested is never good.

Comment: but why create another schema? If I need to get all items in retail, it would not be much more efficent than simply to query jobs then get or edit something in retail, the problem is, I am creating many city, this is one of 15-20 cities, so it would be a problem keeping track of what is going where, thats why I am trying to keep this contained, if you have better plan / docs or readings.. let me know!

Comment: i'm not very good in mongoose, and I don't want to spend 3 months on tutorials and nobody is here to help me, so I am trying to KEEP IT SIMPLE, because when I get stuck, it will be  a hard problem, and I will have to restart the project.. thats my worry here

Comment: Is there some way to I talk to you like discord?

Comment: come here : https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209490/discussion-between-jcx3x-and-larz

Comment: Unfortunately, I need more 10 reputation points to be able to enter in a chat, so if somoeone vote up this answer, I would be able to join

Comment: what is your discord?

Comment: greguintow#9284

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209491/discussion-between-greguintow-and-jcx3x).